# Is there any function for getting a fingerprint image from iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift4, swift4.2

I'm making a program that has a feature to sign in using ONLY! A user fingerprint image from iPhone and matches it among various fingerprint images in the database, so if there is any possible way to get fingerprint image from the user in iPhone?

**(basically, I want to make iPhone works as a fingerprint scanner).**

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to use the camera? or the fingereprint scanner? I don't think that there is an api for the finger print scanner.  As for the camera: it would an awkward experience for the user to wave his finger above the camera, but there is no technically reason why you can't do that.

Comment: Also please note that in many countries it is illegal to store unique identifiers of people such as fingerprints.

Answer (score 4):

No, absolutely not possible. It's against the Apple policy and I would say even their core values. And it is understandable as it would potentially be a very dangerous capability.

From the [Apple documentation on TouchID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication):

> To maximize security, your app never gains access to any of the underlying authentication data.

But you can use the provided authentification API (e.g., to safeguard a given sensible operation).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: API only tells if the fingerprint matches or not, not more than that.

I doubt there is a way due to privacy concerns, not even developers should be supposed to have access to it. Even if that was allowed, security measures should be taken such as having it hashed.