# Capturing Fingeprint on Mobile Apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile, fingerprint, biometrics

Is it possible to capture and store the fingerprint scanned by mobile apps, then store the captured data to a server? I want to make an authentication using fingeprint biometrics, but the fingerprint have to be stored in a server (whether it's in binary or hexadecimal or anything), to facilitate the user can access their data anywhere with any devices with fingerprint biometrics.

I searched the google and found no solution

Comment: Apple doesn't allow this. the biometric authentication is processed on the phone and you can only know if it is valid, I guess it's the same on Android. From the Apple documentation on TouchID: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any function for getting a fingerprint image from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54616373/is-there-any-function-for-getting-a-fingerprint-image-from-iphone)

Comment: On Android, fortunately, [this is is also not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68100136/android-app-only-fingerprint-authentication/68100225?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C55.3103#68100225).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i've been wondering and now I can rest haha